# QtWebegnine jstProcess is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I'm trying to open a simple html file (something like this)

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

which does not have any embedded or external JavaScript, inside QtWebEngine using this code

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class Browser(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Loading ...")
        self.titleChanged.connect(self.adjustTitle)

    def adjustTitle(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Browser()
    view.showMaximized()
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile("simple.html")
    view.setUrl(url)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But when i run it the following error appears in the console

```
js: Uncaught ReferenceError: jstProcess is not defined
```

What is jstProcess and how can i define it? (The code works fine if I load some remote resource like bing.com)

Comment: I have tried your code and I do not have that problem, what version of PyQt5 do you have and what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have 5.9.1 (latest currently in ubuntu repositories) and my OS is ubuntu artful (17.10)

Comment: I have tested it in PyQt5 5.9.2 in Arch Linux and I do not see that problem, it is probably a bug, report it to ubuntu.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks i will

Answer (score 2):

Your eg works for me
 if give a fully qualified file name for simple as
`'/home/me/simple.htm'` . Or if simple.htm is in same directory
where I am running the python I do

```
import sys,os

fname =  os.getcwd()+ '/simple.html'

url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(fname)
```

This is with the pyqt that comes with Debian that I am running 
under python 2.